# How can I fix this Error: TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'access_key'

Tags: python

The following code gives me the Error:

```
 self.porcupine = pvporcupine.create(keywords=self.wake_words)
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'access_key'
```

```
        logger.debug("Initialisiere Wake Word Erkennung...")
        self.wake_words = self.cfg['assistant']['wakewords']
        if not self.wake_words:
            self.wake_words = ['bumblebee']
        logger.debug("Wake Words sind {}", ','.join(self.wake_words))
        self.porcupine = pvporcupine.create(keywords=self.wake_words)
        logger.debug("Wake Word Erkennung wurde initialisiert.")
```

Comment: The definition of the `pvporcupine.create()` method requires that you pass at least one positional argument, and you did not do that.

Comment: It might help to show us the full definition of that method.

Comment: I wish I could, but when I try to edit this to add the whole part, the site tells me it's too much code

Comment: Okay then, the problem is still obvious.  You did not call the function with the correct arguments.  To fix, call it with the correct arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://pypi.org/project/pvporcupine/) documentation. It says you need to pass 2 values to `create` function. The proper usage is:

```
access_key = "${ACCESS_KEY}" # AccessKey obtained from Picovoice Console (https://console.picovoice.ai/)

handle = pvporcupine.create(access_key=access_key, keywords=['picovoice'])
```